# Call a function once per second for 10 seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I need to know how you can perform an operation for total time, I'll explain, I need to repeat my call to a function for 10 seconds and then just every 1, I tried using a timer, but I understand what's called function EVERY 10sec and not FOR 10 sec.

Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "for 10 seconds"? Do you mean you want a call to your function to take ten seconds, or do you want to keep calling your function repeatedly over and over as fast as possible within a ten second period, or...?

Comment: means you want to perform your function check for 10 sec only... for that make two function start timer and stop timer, and call start timer for 10 sec. if with in 10 sec your required things has to be done then stop timer other wise call stop timer after 10 sec..

Comment: i would to execute a command for 10sec and then stop it. In practiche i whant that an uiactivity indicator compare and spin for 10 sec and then stop and disappare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean that you want to call a function once per second, and stop calling it after ten seconds.  And I suspect that you will want to be able to change the interval (once per second) and the duration (10 seconds).

```
@implementation Example
{
    NSTimer *_timer;
    NSTimeInterval _stopTime;
}

- (void)setTimerWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(timerDidFire) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    _stopTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + duration;
}

- (void)timerDidFire
{
    if ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] >= _stopTime) {
        [_timer invalidate];
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"hello from the timer!");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    [super dealloc];  // delete this line if using ARC
}

@end
```

Comment: ..then i can call like this : [self setTimeWithINterval:1 10]; correct?

Comment: `[self setTimerWithInterval:1 duration:10];`

Comment: ..thanks very mutch this evening i try it. The code i need for start my uiactivityindicator i write where now is  NSLog(@"hello from the timer!"); and for stop it after [_timer invalidate]; in dealloc method? correct?

Comment: Yes, replace NSLog with your code.  I don't understand your question about dealloc.  If you need to stop the timer early, send it the `invalidate` message.

Comment: Yes, I need to run a uiactivityindicator for 10 seconds after that I want to disappear. I asked, and the code to make it appear as I put it instead of NSLog while to make it disappear after 10 seconds where I put it?